# Opening .tm files with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, file-extension

The title is self explanatory, but here goes:

I have .tm file in which I have written some source code. 
I want to open the file as a project, similar to .cpp files, when I simply chose to open it with visual studio it opens it as a text file, with no markup.

Comment: What is the .tm extensions mean? It's likely that Visual Studio simply doesn't support it.

Comment: I'm definitely sure that it supports it. And I'm not sure how to explain what it is. I just know that there's some code written in it, and it is an older format used in times of 98 standard c. There should be a way to add any extension to visual studio so that it at least tries to format stuff correctly. And I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: If you edited your question to include a few lines from the .tm file perhaps someone would recognize it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's a simple c++ file, like any other. With a main function and associated other function definitions. The structure is basic .cpp format

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan What happens if you change the ".tm" extension to ".cpp"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton This file is a part of a larger set of files that call to the .tm If I change the extension I'll have to change all the project properties. Anyway I have figured a way to add it as an runnable, project with correct formatting. I'm now adding an answer.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/08/22/using-custom-file-extension-associations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add any extension you need to do the following:

1. Go to Tools
2. Go to Options
3. Go to VC++ Project Settings
4. On the extensions to include line add ;*.whateverExtension
5. Back on the tree form click on Text Editor
6. In the extension box write whateverExtension
7. Chose Visual C++ as editor
8. Click add and OK

And we're fine.